# Control caching for static content

Tags: yesod

I am looking for something like `cacheSeconds` for the subsite generated by `Yesod.Static` in order to control caching of static resources. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Yesod.Static is just a Yesod wrapper around wai-app-static, which is a general purpose WAI static file server. You want to set the [ssMaxAge](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-app-static-2.0.0.2/docs/Network-Wai-Application-Static.html#v%3assMaxAge) setting. Depending on exactly what your code looks like now, this could be something along the lines of:

```
Static settings <- static "/some/static/path"
let newStatic = Static $ settings { ssMaxAge = NoMaxAge }
```